# Which one is the right way to add geolocation meta info to a site?

Tags: html, geolocation, metadata

I'm looking how to add meta info to a page.
One way is the meta tag

```
<metatag name="country" content="Canada" />
```

another I saw is

```
<metatag name="geo.country" content="CA" />
```

using the ISO 3166.

I like the second one because is standard with ISO and easy to understand by crawlers.
Which one of these options is standard? Or most of the crawlers accept them ?

I know that Google does not use any of them, but Bing does.

One site is for desktop web browsers and another one is for WAP (mobile) browsers. Is there any difference?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use both? BTW it's `<meta />` not `<metatag />`

From what I've seen, though, geo.country may be the way to go.

http://marketingblogonline.com/geo-tag-seo.html

I still don't see any reason not to use both, though.

EDIT: Actually, poking around a little more I see that `<meta name="country">` doesn't seem to be doing much– http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=0610ddf168b8d424&hl=en.

You also want to consider that a global business *probably shouldn't* have a country tied to it, anyway. Otherwise you're limiting your customer base.

But, if you are certain that making your website local will help your business, I have just read that HTML5's `lang` attribute identifies both country and language.

```
<html lang="en-US">
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1 –– List of country codes

http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4646.txt –– How to write the lang attribute.

Comment: If you use the first choice in which language do you write the country name? English? local language?
(Ex: <metatag name="country" content="España" />)

Comment: I edited my original answer to reflect new information I have learned.

Comment: `You also want to consider that a global business probably shouldn't have a country tied to it, anyway. Otherwise you're limiting your customer base.`


Just to give an example in [Renxo](http://www.renxo.com/) each top subfolder is for a different country.

Comment: Are you rebutting that, or agreeing?

Comment: It's a rebutting if you want. 
It's just an example where you have parts of the site that are just for one country. You could find another top companies that use the same strategy.

Comment: You're right in that regard. However, Renxo is not a global business. It is specifically geared towards those three American countries and should not show up when I search for `ringtones` in Azerbaijan. Hence Renxo has `<meta name="geo.country" content="AR" />`, etc tags on each of it's individual pages. There's nothing wrong with country specific subdomains. Only don't use the `geo.country` tag for services provided globally– like Gmail.