# How to say to google that my subdomain is targeted to a specific country

Tags: subdomain, google-search, geotargetting

I have these subdomains:

- `uk.example.com`
- `india.example.com`
- `es.example.com`

And each one has content specific per each country.

If I go to google.co.uk I have to see only contents from `uk.example.com`.

Which is the right metadata for this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not related to programming. Try asking on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:

> Google does not use locational meta tags (like geo.position or
>   distribution) or HTML attributes for geotargeting.

So, you can't use `<html lang="en-UK">` as I originally said.

But it seems from here:

> The first three elements used for geotargeting are strongly tied to
>   the server and to the URLs used. It's difficult to determine
>   geotargeting on a page by page basis, so it makes sense to consider
>   using a URL structure that makes it easy to segment parts of the
>   website for geotargeting.

that specifying a url, like you did, is enough!

*source: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.il/2010/03/working-with-multi-regional-websites.html or https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en#2*

---

**OLD POST:**

Google supports `rel hreflang`

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://www.example.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es-ES" href="http://es-es.example.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es-MX" href="http://es-mx.example.com/" /> 
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://en.example.com/" />
```

(*source: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.dk/2011/12/new-markup-for-multilingual-content.html*)

but if you're buying new domains, it's best to have correct ccTLD:

> If you use a ccTLD or a gTLD together with Webmaster Tools, then we'll mainly use the >geotargeting from there

(*source: http://www.seroundtable.com/seo-geo-location-server-google-17468.html*)

see also:

- [Which one is the right way to add geolocation meta info to a site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588857/which-one-is-the-right-way-to-add-geolocation-meta-info-to-a-site)
- http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2013/05/6-quick-tips-for-international-websites.html

Answer (score 1):

> You can use the geotargeting tool in Webmaster Tools to indicate to Google that your site is targeted at a specific country. Do this only if your site has a gTLD (generic top-level domain name). However, don’t use this tool if your site targets more than a single country. For example, it would make sense to set a target of Canada for a site about restaurants in Montreal; but it would not make sense to set the same target for a site that targets French speakers in France, Canada, and Mali."

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en#2